# How can I rename a menu machine name in drupal 8

Tags: 8

I ve migrated my D6 site to D8. And now I'd like to rename my menu machine names(not the system menus my custom menus) to a different ones. I'd want to do this either on database or from code.

Any ideas??

Comment: Machine names are often not changeable as it is very hard to predict what would need to change. For example, block plugins are created based on those machine names, renaming that would break those blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the problem when I needed to rename the machine name of my custom menus. In my case, I needed to remove hyphens in the machine name (this is a known issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1353064), because some modules don't support hyphens. How I fixed it:

1. First of all you need to update already existing menu items (bundle, name, parent and etc.) I did it directly in a database through hook_update in your_custom_module:

```
function your_custom_module_update_8008() {
  $database = \Drupal::database();

  $menus = [
    'example-menu-machine-name-1' => 'examplemenumachinename1',
    'example-menu-machine-name-2' => 'examplemenumachinename2',
  ];

  foreach ($menus as $old_machine_name => $new_machine_name) {
    $database->update('menu_link_content')
      ->expression('bundle', "REPLACE(bundle, :old_value, :new_value)", [
        ':old_value' => $old_machine_name,
        ':new_value' => $new_machine_name,
      ])
      ->execute();
    $database->update('menu_link_content_data')
      ->expression('menu_name', "REPLACE(menu_name, :old_value, :new_value)", [
        ':old_value' => $old_machine_name,
        ':new_value' => $new_machine_name,
      ])
      ->expression('bundle', "REPLACE(bundle, :old_value, :new_value)", [
        ':old_value' => $old_machine_name,
        ':new_value' => $new_machine_name,
      ])
      ->execute();

    $database->update('menu_tree')
      ->expression('menu_name', 'REPLACE(menu_name, :old_value, :new_value)', [
        ':old_value' => $old_machine_name,
        ':new_value' => $new_machine_name,
      ])
      ->expression('id', 'REPLACE(id, :old_value, :new_value)', [
        ':old_value' => $old_machine_name,
        ':new_value' => $new_machine_name,
      ])
      ->expression('parent', 'REPLACE(parent, :old_value, :new_value)', [
        ':old_value' => $old_machine_name,
        ':new_value' => $new_machine_name,
      ])
      ->execute();
  }
}
```

2. Rename these names in configs. Your IDE should help with this. Don't forget also about renaming files for configs. For example:
   **system.menu.example-menu-machine-name-1.yml** to **system.menu.examplemenumachinename1.yml**
3. If you have custom templates for menus also rename them:
   **menu--example-menu-machine-name-1.html.twig** to **menu--examplemenumachinename1.html.twig**
4. Adjust classes in CSS|SCSS files, because they will be changed after renaming. Use IDE for this, it will save time :)
5. Run your build process locally and check results.
6. Take the dump of the database from the production and run a build with this database locally. Please compare menus between the local version and the production on the frontend.

Comment: Some further tips in extra:

• If you have any custom fields on your entity type, then add extra `$database->update('table_name')` code blocks for them as well.

• If revisions are enabled for your entity type, then also check your DB structure to see how many extra tables needs to be updated.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but you can try [node clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) and then clone a menu after that you can set the machine name.